# Unable to save after adding new column of sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have encounter some difficulties saving my data after i added new column to my sqlite. e.g the column_contact_grp in the example below

in my contract class:

```
 public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME = "name";
    public final static String COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER = "number";
    public final static String COLUMN_CONTACT_GRP = "group";
```

in my Dbhelper class:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the pets table
    String SQL_CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + NameEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + NameEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NameEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + NameEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
            + NameEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_GRP + " TEXT );";

    // Execute the SQL statement
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

in my Main Activity:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NameEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME, "Name");
    values.put(NameEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER, "1234");
    values.put(NameEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_GRP, "testing");
```

The program "used to work and save well" but it fail saving when i added a new data. When i remove the additional code (COLUMN_CONTACT_GRP related codes), it will work again, able to save and display name and number correctly on my listview. Anyone can guide where should i look out for the errors?

Answer (score 2):

word "group" is SQLite keywords, use another keyword, check this [link](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should use **[onUpgrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int))** Method .

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
>   should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else
>   it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 1) { // Add your Version .
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER);
    }

}


 private static final String DATABASE_ALTER = "ALTER TABLE "
    + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_ONE + " string;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase your DataBase Version and in onUpgrade method write to query to add a column in the table.